# escaping ampersand when returned by awk

Tags: bash, awk, zsh, ampersand

I'm using
`echo $(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | grep "SSID:" | grep -v "BSSID" | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'`
to get the wifi name for zsh prompt.

it works fine with standard names but if the name has any non-standard characters i.e. 'B&Q_Public' it only returns B and then says

`(eval):1: command not found: Q`

Any suggestions

Comment: Post the output of `airport -I` so we can see the data you are dealing with.

Comment: @Simon Harvey, It is always recommended to post samples of input and expected output too in your post, kindly do so.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem.

Comment: when this is run in bash it works but when It's called by mt .zshrc file it errors `POWERLEVEL9K_CUSTOM_SSID="echo $(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | awk -F ": " '/ SSID:/{print $2}')"` this is whats generating the `(eval):1: command not found:` error. I'm also wondering if its because the SSID i'm testing it against has a space in `SSID: B&Q Public` and not as posted before  `B&Q_Public`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the long path of the `airport` utility is awfully unwieldy. Let's make a symlink.

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/bin/airport
```

Assuming a program output like this (based on some googling I've taken [this](https://github.com/schollz/find/issues/14#issuecomment-211289535) as an example):

```
     agrCtlRSSI: -76
     agrExtRSSI: 0
    agrCtlNoise: -92
    agrExtNoise: 0
          state: running
        op mode: station
     lastTxRate: 24
        maxRate: 54
lastAssocStatus: 0
    802.11 auth: open
      link auth: wpa2-psk
          BSSID: c0:3e:f:2f:c3:ad
           SSID: B&Q_Public
            MCS: -1
        channel: 4
```

and a desired result of just `B&Q_Public` (the SSID), it's enough to use a single `awk` command:

```
airport -I | awk -F ": " '/ SSID:/{print $2}'
```

Notes:

- The field separator is set to `': '`, the values will always be in `$2`.
- There is space before `SSID:`, this prevents matching the line with `BSSID:`.
- There is no need to run `grep` twice here, `awk` can hold up just fine.

There is no `eval` being run anywhere here so I don't think this line alone can produce the error you show.